# What is a 6-string bass guitar with normal guitar tuning called?

Tags: electric-guitar, terminology, bass-guitar

As I know, there're 6-string bass with `B – E – A – D – G - C` tuning. But, MusicMan release kind-of 6-string bass with guitar tuning which is `E - A - D - G - B - e`. You can see the bass [here](http://www.music-man.com/instruments/guitars/silhouette-bass.html).

Is it still called as a 6-string bass guitar, or is it have another name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "Bass VI" applies to the Music Man Silhouette Baritone Bass.

The Bass VI name comes from the Fender Bass VI introduced in 1961 before "normal" six string basses existed (or at least were widely known).  At least some other makers, e.g. Eastwood t (Sidejack Bass VI) and Schecter (Hellcat vi), have adopted this naming.  This is one of those cases where a specific company's product's name has taken on a more general application (like Kleenex) so some manufacturers, like Ernie Ball, will avoid using the term.

The "bass vi" moniker implies relatively tight string spacing (closer to guitar string spacing) and 30" scale length, features that make it more similar to playing a guitar (for example playing slap on one would be next to impossible).  Indeed, the Fender Bass VI was originally marketed as allowing guitarists to easily play bass.

This term would not be applicable to a regular 6 string bass that just happens to be in guitar tuning, which I would call a "6 string bass in guitar tuning" if I needed to be specific.

Comment: Your last para. sums it up well!!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it could be a baritone guitar, although there is a model that is tuned A-A. The strings don't look very thick. The reason most BASSES are tuned BEADGC is to keep the 4th tuning between strings. The reason GUITARS are tuned EADGBE is to facilitate chord playing. Generally, basses are not used for chord work, so this is maybe an attempt to get ordinary guitarists to have a go on bass? I guess you've quoted the MM 'bass' strings high to low.

Comment: But there is a guitar that is called [baritone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baritone_guitar) and it's different

Comment: @Shevliaskovic - see Dave's answer.